# Set variables from CSV using Python

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to set variables based on a csv file using Python. I have two columns in my CSV file and would like to set the variables in one of two ways.

mycsv.csv is set up in the following way:

```
moogah,bar
foo,test
```

First way:

```
string = str(lineEdit.text())

with open('mycsv.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == string:
            setFirst = str(row[0])
            setSecond = str(row[1])
            QMessageBox.information(None, 'myvariable %s' % setFirst)
```

If 'foo' is typed into the lineEdit, this should set the variables like so:

```
setFirst = 'foo'
setSecond = 'test'
```

It's for a QGIS plugin and the variables are not being properly set. The QMessageBox only displays 'myvariable' and not the actual result even when the strings match. I'm guessing there's a problem with the CSV reader.

Second way I'm looking to do it is with dict:

```
with open('mycsv.csv', 'rb') as f:
    myDict = dict(csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
```

I'm not correctly comparing my lineEdit input string with the dictionary items, because I don't always get desired results.

```
myDict = {'moogah':'bar', 'foo':'test'} 

for key in myDict.keys():
    for value in myDict.values():
        if key == string:
            variable1 = key
            variable2 = value
```

I got a result once where variable1 = 'moogah' and variable2 = 'test', while I want it to always be:

```
scenario 1: variable1 = moogah AND variable2 = bar
scenerio 2: variable1 = foo AND variable2 = test
```

Comment: It's not clear what your actual question is here...  can you elaborate on what kind of help you need?

Comment: @AndrewMiner I just updated my question to explain the issue. I'm a beginner to python and figured there would be some glaring mistake with my csv reader use.

Comment: Well firstly you need a double equals for comparisons in your if statement!

Comment: @three_pineapples thanks for pointing out my typo--still didn't solve my problem

Comment: Please post at least the CSV file...questions asking for debugging help are supposed to include a minimilistic working example.

Comment: @three_pineapples Just posted the csv. Apologies, i figured the code with dict() was enough to give an idea of how the csv file is, after mentioning in the beginning that it has two rows.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the correct way to iterate through my dictionary, so I've decided to go with the second way (though I'm still not sure why the first way doesn't work, so please do comment if you'd like to).

```
for key, value in myDict.items():
    if key == string:
        variable 1 == key
        variable 2 == value
```